# Error "No url is set" at row editing in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, dialog

I Found dialog with text "No url is set" when edit row at jqgrid. After press enter, i found dialog with text "No url is set".
anyone can help me about this problem?

This is my jqgrid code

```
function callIdGrid() {
    var lastSel;
    jQuery("#id_grid").jqGrid({
        height:200,
        width:655,
        colNames:['Name','Address','Amount'],
        colModel:[{
            name:'acctId',
            index:'acctId',
            width:150,
            editable:true
        },{
            name:'address',
            index:'address',
            width:150,
            editable:true
            }
        },{
            name:'amount',
            index:'amount',
            formatter:'currency',
            width:150,
            editable:true
        }],
        pager: '#id_pager',
        sortname: 'acctId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Accounts",
        cellEdit: true,
        editurl:"noabjad.json",
        onSelectRow: function(acctId){
        if(acctId && acctId!==lastSel){
        jQuery('#id_grid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
        jQuery('#id_grid').jqGrid('editRow',acctId,true,onSaveSuccess);
        lastSel=acctId;
        }
        }
        editurl: 'clientArray'
    }) ;
    jQuery("#id_grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#id_pager',{
        add:true,
        del:false,
        search:false,
        edit:true
    },{
        reloadAfterSubmit:false
    },{
        reloadAfterSubmit:false
    }).navButtonAdd("#id_pager",{
        caption:"",
        buttonicon:"",
        onClickButton:function(){
        var datarow = {acctId: "", address: "", amount: ""};
        var su=jQuery("#id_grid").addRowData("X",datarow,"first");
        if(su) { jQuery("#id_grid").setSelection('X') }
    }

    });
    function onSaveSuccess(xhr){
        response = xhr.responseText;
        if(response == 1) return true; return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you use? [Inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing), [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) or [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)? Which `datatype` has the jqGrid? It's better if you modify the text of your question and include the definition of the jqGrid inside.

Comment: i've found dialog alert "No Url is set" at editing mode, cell editing.What can i do?

Comment: You can **include the JavaScript code which you currently use** and which can use other to reproduce your problem in the text of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many grids are on the page? In the code which you posted you defines jqGrid `"#id_grid"` with the pager "#id_grid". On the other side inside of `onClickButton` of the `navButtonAdd` and inside of the `onSelectRow` you use inline editing of *another grid*: `"#TransaksiDisbursed"`.

Did you defined `editurl` parameter (like `editurl: 'clientArray'`) for the second (`"#TransaksiDisbursed"`) grid or existing `"#TransaksiDisbursed"` in your code is just cut&paste error?

Comment: im sorry, "TransaksiDisbursed" should "id_grid".

Comment: @soccerenz: Is the problem is solved after the usage of "id_grid" instead of "TransaksiDisbursed"?

Comment: Im so sorry, im not understand...Please understand, sorry bother you.=)
yes, problem is solved after the usage of "id_grid".

Comment: @soccerenz: You are welcome! Solved problems are the problems which I like mostly! :-)

Comment: Im so sorry ,but "No url is set" still exist after i edit row and then i press enter. I dont know what...but this is complicate.
do you can help me?

Comment: @soccerenz: Could you post the last version of the code which you use? It's better if you post the HTML code inclusive the list of JavaScript files which yo use.

Comment: im sorry, but i not use pure HTML code, but mostly zkoss and little html code.

Comment: @soccerenz: Is the JavaScript code from your question is what you use currently? It is not important which technology you use on the server side. If you open the page source in the web browser you will see pure HTML and pure JavaScripts. Moreover it is still unclear for me how you fill the grid. You don't defines and `datatype` and no `url` parameters. How you fill the grid?

Comment: This is a chronology: iam added row with button navigation contained in my code above.And then i click one row for edit, after i edit, and then i press enter.But that visible is dialog "No url is set". sorry bother you =)

Answer (score 1):

`editRow()` has only two params, I'm not sure your code works

`jQuery('#id_grid').jqGrid('editRow',acctId,true,onSaveSuccess);`

`editRow(rowid, keys)` - accept two parameters:

1. `rowid` - the unique id of the row
2. `keys` - which when true - we can use Enter and Escape keys to save and cancel editing